# Cmake: How to link multiple libraries?

Tags: c++, cmake, build, shared-libraries, cmakelists-options

I am using CMake to define the compilation of a C++ executable. The goal is to use 2 third-party libraries, Open3D and OpenCV. I am able to include one of the two with `target_link_libraries`, but including both results in OpenCV functions not being found.

This is my current `CMakeLists.txt`

```
minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(ORB_SLAM)

find_package(Open3D REQUIRED)
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
add_executable(ORB_SLAM src/main.cpp)

#target_link_libraries(ORB_SLAM ${Open3D_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(ORB_SLAM ${OpenCV_LIBS})

# When printed, ${Open3D_LIBRARIES} = Open3D::Open3D
#               ${OpenCV_LIBS} = opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;...many more..;opencv_xphoto
```

With this `CMakeList.txt`, I can successfully use OpenCV functions. By using the commented out Open3D `target_link_libraries`, I can successfully use Open3D. When uncommenting both `target_link_libraries`, it fails to find OpenCV functionality, regardless of the order of the `find_package` and `target_link_libraries`. The same error even occurs if I include both in a single `target_link_libraries(ORB_SLAM ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${Open3D_LIBRARIES})`. The same error occurs for CMake 3.16.3 and 3.21.3.

The error is as follows:

```
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/ORB_SLAM.dir/src/main.cpp.o: in function `main':
/home/m/CLionProjects/ORB_SLAM/src/main.cpp:20: undefined reference to `cv::VideoCapture::VideoCapture(std::string const&, int)'
```

For the code

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/videoio.hpp>
//#include <open3d/Open3D.h>

int main() {
    cv::VideoCapture cap("/home/.../scene.mp4");
    //auto sphere = open3d::geometry::TriangleMesh::CreateSphere(1.0);  
}
```

It seems as though `Open3D::Open3D` takes precedence over `opencv_calib3d;opencv_core;...`. What is causing this and how can I fix it? Is this perhaps due to the discrepancy in Open3D's "::" vs OpenCV's lowercase notation?

Edit: Here is a dump of all CMake variables if it is of any use https://textuploader.com/t5dvl/raw

Excuse my inexperience. I have searched through CMake documentation and Stackoverflow questions for a lead, but so far I have found nothing.

Comment: Related question that I could not find a way to use: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15207297/how-to-link-multiple-libraries-using-cmake

Comment: It seems as though this is a documented problem, specifically the Open3D OpenCV combination. https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues/2286
I will attempt the fix mention in that thread and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by finding this Github issue: https://github.com/isl-org/Open3D/issues/2286
By using specific build flags when building Open3D, the libraries could both be linked correctly and simultaneously with the `target_link_libraries(ORB_SLAM ${OpenCV_LIBS} ${Open3D_LIBRARIES})` command.

The build commands were as follows;

```
git clone --recursive https://github.com/intel-isl/Open3D
cd Open3D && source util/scripts/install-deps-ubuntu.sh
mkdir build && cd build
cmake -DBUILD_EIGEN3=ON -DBUILD_GLEW=ON -DBUILD_GLFW=ON -DBUILD_JSONCPP=ON -DBUILD_PNG=ON -DGLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=ON -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE=/usr/bin/python -DBUILD_UNIT_TESTS=ON ..
make -j4
sudo make install
```